# Скрытие блока на CSS с динамической высотой

Tags: html, css, css3

Нужно на CSS сделать анимацию скрытия и отображения полей в `"main-wrap"` методом изменения высоты вложенных элементов.

Для примера привел два - `"description"` и `"select-menu"`.

При этом меню может оставаться как в свернутым так и развернутым, а также ни у одного из вложенных элементов не может быть `overflow:hidden`. Поэтому `max-height:0; to max-height: ...px` не подходит.

Пробовали реализовать на `transform scaleY(0 to 1)`, но тогда остается занимаемое блоком место, а этого хотим избежать.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.main-wrap').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('minified')) {
      $this.removeClass('minified')
    }
  });
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.main-wrap').addClass('minified');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('.select-menu-wrap').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible-menu');
  });
  $('.select-menu-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-menu-title').addClass('is-selected').find('.selected').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
.main-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.minified .description {
  display: none;
}
.minified .select-menu-wrap {
  display: none;
}
.minified button {
  display: none;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40%;
}
.select-menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.select-menu {
  display: none;
  padding: 4px;
}
.visible-menu .select-menu {
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  display: none;
}
.select-menu-title {
  padding: 4px;
}
.is-selected .selected {
  display: inline;
}
.is-selected .no-selected {
  display: none;
}
.description {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap minified">
  <div class="title">Заголовок всегда виден. Нажмите на блок, чтобы  развернуть</div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="description">Тут пояснение, что к чему.</div>
  <div class="select-menu-wrap">
    <div class="select-menu-title">
      <span class="no-selected">Нажмите сюда, чтобы выбрать из списка</span>
      <span class="selected"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="select-menu">
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 1</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 2</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Свернуть</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 12px;">Здесь текст, чтобы видеть как блок с ним взаимодействует.</div>
```

Comment: вопрос: почему, собственно, нельзя использовать `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: так как внутри, например, редактируемого DIV есть редактор который летает за выделением и может выходить за границы блока, ну и еще у других блоков которые я не навел в данном примере есть разные состояния - тултипы и тд.

Comment: такой вопрос: в чем, собственное, суть изменения высоты элементов? вот вам привел такой пример: https://jsfiddle.net/bgvccjk7/  - правильно ли я вас понял? вам нужно показывать/скрывать формы?

Comment: Для анимации можно использовать animate.css

Comment: Прошу смотреть метки по заданию css,css3!  jquery - не подходит, при чем принципиально, animate.css не нашел нужного эффекта, и готовые решения не приветствую, так как будут висеть неиспользуемые строки кода

Comment: @sivik_xes позвольте уточнить, какой профит от `css` анимации если всеравно юзаете `js` ?

Comment: Так как сss анимация дешевле чем js, а так же выполняется отдельно, если js будет выполнять ресурсоемкую задачу и в это же время анимацию, то он пожертвует анимацией и снизит частоту кадров прорисовки. а css в этом плане изолирована и следовательно лучше подходит для текущей задачи.

Comment: @sivik_xes Спасибо за ответ. Что ж, желаю удачи в этом деле. Лично я бы предпочел использовать `js` анимацию конкретно в данном контексте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение, правда немножко не верное предположение было в условии, оказывается что `scale + max-height` примерно тоже, что и `hidden + max-height`, но только без `hidden`, просто ранее не пробовал их совмещать))

```js
$(function() {
  $('.main-wrap').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('minified')) {
      $this.removeClass('minified')
    }
  });
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.main-wrap').addClass('minified');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('.select-menu-wrap').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible-menu');
  });
  $('.select-menu-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-menu-title').addClass('is-selected').find('.selected').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
}
.main-wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 10px 80px;
  position: relative;
}
.minified .description {
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear 250ms, max-height 300ms linear 250ms, margin 300ms linear 250ms, padding 300ms linear 250ms;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.minified .select-menu-wrap {
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear 250ms, max-height 300ms linear 250ms, margin 300ms linear 250ms, padding 300ms linear 250ms;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.minified button {
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear 250ms, max-height 300ms linear 250ms, margin 300ms linear 250ms, padding 300ms linear 250ms;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 40%;
  transition: transform 300ms linear, max-height 300ms linear, margin 300ms linear, padding 300ms linear, opacity 300ms linear 300ms;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
.select-menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  transition: transform 300ms linear, max-height 300ms linear, margin 300ms linear, padding 300ms linear, opacity 300ms linear 300ms;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
.select-menu {
  transition: opacity 300ms linear, transform 300ms linear 250ms, max-height 300ms linear 250ms, margin 300ms linear 250ms, padding 300ms linear 250ms;
  transform-origin: top;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}
.visible-menu .select-menu {
  transition: transform 300ms linear, max-height 300ms linear, margin 300ms linear, padding 300ms linear, opacity 300ms linear 300ms;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
.selected {
  display: none;
}
.select-menu-title {
  padding: 4px;
}
.is-selected .selected {
  display: inline;
}
.is-selected .no-selected {
  display: none;
}
.description {
  margin: 10px 0;
  transition: transform 300ms linear, max-height 300ms linear, margin 300ms linear, padding 300ms linear, opacity 300ms linear 300ms;
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap minified">
  <div class="title">Заголовок всегда виден. Нажмите на блок, чтобы развернуть</div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="description">Тут пояснение, что к чему.</div>
  <div class="select-menu-wrap">
    <div class="select-menu-title">
      <span class="no-selected">Нажмите сюда, чтобы выбрать из списка</span>
      <span class="selected"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="select-menu">
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 1</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 2</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Свернуть</button>
</div>

<div style="margin-top: 12px;">Здесь текст, чтобы видеть как блок с ним взаимодействует.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сразу скажу, что `overflow: hidden` я все же использовал, но только, чтобы визуально ограничить перемещения элементов. В принципе, можно избежать и этого, используя нужные `z-index` и заливки `div` цветами. В общем, кое-что получилось, надеюсь, это вам поможет.

[КодПеро](http://codepen.io/malginovdesign/pen/VaVZvJ)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.main-wrap').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('minified')) {
      $this.removeClass('minified')
    }
  });
  $('button').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.main-wrap').addClass('minified');
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $('.select-menu-wrap').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('visible-menu');
  });
  $('.select-menu-item').on('click', function() {
    $('.select-menu-title').addClass('is-selected').find('.selected').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300&subset=latin,cyrillic);

* {
  outline: none;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: url(http://malginovdesign.ru/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/head-bg.png);
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-wrap {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    padding: 15px 10px 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    top: 50px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.main-wrap, .select-menu-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.title:active {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.title:hover {
    background: #eee;
}
.title, .select-menu-title {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 0;
    margin: 0 40px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
.minified .description, .minified .select-menu-wrap {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -999px;
}

.visible-menu .select-menu {
      opacity: 1;
      top: 0;
    position: relative;
}

  .minified button {
  display: none;
}
button:active {
    background: #e0e0e0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
button:hover {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 50px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    border: none;
    background: #fafafa;
    padding: 8px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.description, .select-menu-wrap {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
.description {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 0 40px;
}
.select-menu {
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -999px;
}
.select-menu-item {
    padding: 8px 0;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    margin: 0 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  display: none;
}
.is-selected .selected {
  display: inline;
}
.is-selected .no-selected {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-wrap minified">
  <div class="title">Развернуть меню</div>
  <div contenteditable="true" class="description">Тут пояснение, что к чему.</div>
  <div class="select-menu-wrap">
    <div class="select-menu-title">
      <span class="no-selected">Выбрать позицию</span>
      <span class="selected"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="select-menu">
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 1</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 2</div>
      <div class="select-menu-item">Позиция 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Свернуть</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Извините не могу засчитать данный ответ как верный, owerflow не подходит, да и анимация сама по себе не очень, там этих блоков очень много, и из за position absolute  нету эффекта плавного изменения высоты общего wrap